# Pixelated wallpaper/background

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, desktop-background

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P today.
Everything worked fine, but after installing my graphics card driver the background became pixelated (Nvidia GeForce GT755m). I downloaded the driver through Additional Drivers and selected Version 331.113 (Proprietary, tested). It was using Nouveau before.

When I apply Nouveau it becomes clean again, but it is much weaker when I open games, it gives me very low FPS even in Counter-Strike.
With Nvidia driver FPS and everything else seems fine, except things look pixelated and when I minimize windows and maximize again, the window goes black.

[image]

I attempted to solve the problem myself by removing the old Nvidia driver and manually installing the latest version, but it did not help.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with nvidia settings i found the solution.

If you are experiencing the same problem do the following steps to solve the problem.

1. Open NVIDIA X Server Settings
2. Click the GPU that is used for your display. (In my case GPU 0)
   Under the GPU submenu click DFP-1
3. At the right choose the Controls tab.
4. Set the options as the following

   Deithering: Enabled.

   Mode: to Auto

   Depth: 6 bpc.

You can also see the settings in the following picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Gnome Tweak tool under appearance you can set the adjustment for background and lock screen as 'None'. This fixed the problem for me.